# Find a pair of integers from an array that sums up to a given number in Java 8 using functionals

Tags: java, arrays, functional-programming, java-8

I was looking at the problem of finding a pair of two integers from an array that sums up to a given number in Java in a different way.
I wanted to use Java 8 functionals. I tried something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        List<Integer> res = IntStream.of(arr).boxed().filter(x -> x + arr[i] == givenNumber)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

but it won't work(error) because "arr[i]" is not final and can't be final in my approach. Can something like:
        filter(x -> y -> x + y == givenNumber) with x and y from arr work somehow?

So could this be done in Java 8 using functional programming? If the answer is yes, then how?

Comment: Just use an intermediate variable `int i0 = i;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* make them final.  If nothing else, you can write

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    final int[] arrFinal = arr;
    final int iFinal = i;
    List<Integer> res = IntStream.of(arr).boxed()
        .filter(x -> x + arrFinal[iFinal] == givenNumber)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

though I'd write it as

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int target = givenNumber - arr[i];
    List<Integer> res = IntStream.of(arr).filter(x -> x == target)
                           .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

...which also makes it clear, for what it's worth, that you're just going to have a list of a single value repeated some number of times, which might reshape your program in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

These are called `complementary pairs` and it's totally doable just with streams:

```
 private static void showPairs(int k, int[] array) {

    IntStream.range(0, array.length)
            .boxed()
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i, array.length)
                    .boxed()
                    .filter(j -> k - array[i] == array[j])
                    .flatMap(j -> Stream.of(new int[] { i, j }, new int[] { j, i }))) // [i, j] and [j, i]
            .forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        final int pos = i;
        Arrays.stream(array).skip(pos + 1).filter(element -> array[pos] + element == sumTarget).forEach(element -> {
            set.add("{" + array[pos] + ", " + element + "}");
        });
    }
    set.forEach(System.out::println);
```